# Use Stokes' theorem to find area of a surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

Can you think of a way to apply Stokes' theorem to find the area of a surface in $\mathbb{R^3}$ by
constructing some vector field $F(x, y, z)$ and taking its line integral over the boundary
of the surface?

If $n$ is the normal vector to the surface, then I need to find some vector field $F(x,y,z)$ such that $\langle \operatorname{curl} F, n\rangle = |n|$, right?

Or $\langle \operatorname{curl} F, n\rangle = 1$ ? Why? I'm confused with this! Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Comment: $1$ is correct, because the integral is with respect to $dS$, the element of surface area.